# Pandana OSM loader does not recognize bbox

Tags: python, gis, openstreetmap, bounding-box, osmnx

I am trying to perform some analysis using Pandana on the city of Santiago de Chile.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandana
from pandana.loaders import osm

bbox = [-70.80063634909742,
 -33.65910544543891,
 -70.46303984334773,
 -33.29788325657151] # my SCL bounding box 

network = osm.pdna_network_from_bbox(bbox[0],bbox[1],bbox[2],bbox[3])
```

but I get the error

```
Exception: Query resulted in no data. Check your query parameters: [out:json][timeout:180];(way["highway"]["highway"!~"motor|proposed|construction|abandoned|platform|raceway"]["foot"!~"no"]["pedestrians"!~"no"](-70.80063635,-33.65910545,-70.46303984,-33.29788326);>;);out;
```

I have no idea why this bbox does not work, it works with other libraries **and** this pandana (actually osm) function works with other bboxes.

Are you able to suggest me the cause of the error?
Otherwise, is it possible to convert a OSMNX graph, that I was easily able to build, into a Pandana graph?

Answer (score 0):

Bounding box formatted as a 4 element tuple: (lng_max, lat_min, lng_min, lat_max)

network = osm.pdna_network_from_bbox(lat_min=bbox[0],lng_min=bbox[1], lat_max=bbox[2], lng_max=bbox[3])